# Tengo problemas con una aplicación batch

Tags: batch

¿Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de que cuando abra una carpeta con un archivo batch arrastrándola hacia él y la borre? Pero el archivo batch no sabe en que ruta se encuentra la carpeta, sino, que debe encontrarla. Mas bien lo que quiero lograr es que cuando abra cualquier carpeta con ese archivo batch este haga una búsqueda de esa carpeta para encontrar su ruta.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a `%1`? (Esto https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)